# Java maven - IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set

Tags: java, maven

I get the following errror when I use git bash command - however when I run the test in Intellij everything works fine and test starts. Could you help ?

mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@desktop"

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require.nonNull(Require.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:77)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:46)
        at utils.Utils.waitForElement(Utils.java:28)
        at pages.LandingPage.acceptConsent(LandingPage.java:21)
```

Feature file

```
 @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page
    Given Customer accepts cookie consent
    And I click "OK" button at the bottom of the page
```

POM

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/picocontainer/picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
            <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.monochromata.cucumber/reporting-plugin -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TestRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>Cucumber</projectName>
                            <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsonReports</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->

                            <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                            <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                            <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the same test from different test runs -->
                            <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                            <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                            <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Intellij configuration where it works
[image]

Comment: I believe that you just pass `null` to your waiter at `Utils.java:28`

Answer (score 0):

The error message "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set" says that the issue is with the code and not with the tool or IDE. This error occurs when a null or empty input is passed into a method that is not programmed accept it. In this case, it is happening when creating an object of the `FluentWait` class from the `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui` package.

Based on the provided information, the issue seems to be related how `waitForElement()` method in the `Utils` class is implemented. This method is trying to create an object of the `FluentWait` class, but the input provided to this class is empty, which is causing the exception to be thrown.

To fix this issue, we need to pass the correct input parameter to the `FluentWait` class. In the waitForElement() method, we need to pass the `WebDriver` instance as a parameter to the `FluentWait` constructor. Here is how we can modify the code:

```
public static void waitForElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
```

In this code, `driver` instance is being passes as a parameter to the `FluentWait` constructor. Along with it the `element` instance to the `visibilityOf()` method of the `ExpectedConditions` class is also being passed. The element instance is passed to the `until()` method of the `wait` instance. This ensures that the wait will be executed only until the element becomes visible.

Once you make the above changes, you can rerun the `mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@desktop"` command, and the error should be resolved.

Comment: I added the screenshot from intellij where it works

Comment: hello, do you maybe know the solution ? Running through Intellij works, but not through mvn

Comment: maybe any dependecy is missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your cocumber test runner class. In 'glue' option you should show where you keep:

1. steps
2. hooks

I bet that you have some helper class where you have hooks like @Before and @After. Im sure you are missing the second point here.

Example code:

@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/java/features",
glue = {"steps", **"base"**}
)

Answer (score 0):

I got almost identical console output as what you shared above. A certain test of mine would not even run the first step, which told me it had something to do with my 'DriverUtils' or my 'Hooks'.

The beginning of my feature file:

```
@ProdSmoke @TC1.38 @ARCCP-T138 @TestCaseKey=ARCCP-T138
Scenario: User logs in, clicks essential buttons, logs out, logs in, logs out

    # navigate to PROD CLIENT PORTAL
Given user navigates to "https://our-website-url.com/login"
And user has entered valid prod username and valid password
```

My Hooks file looked like this:

```
import api.services.AuthenticationControllerService;
import context.SharedContext;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import utils.CommonMethods;
import utils.ConfigReader;
import utils.DriverUtils;

public class Hooks {
    private static String authorizationToken = "";
    AuthenticationControllerService authenticationControllerService = new AuthenticationControllerService();
    @Before("@UI")
    public void setUp() {
        ConfigReader.initializeProperties();
        DriverUtils.createDriver();
    }
    @Before("@API")
    public void setupBaseURIGetToken(){
        ConfigReader.initializeProperties();
        RestAssured.baseURI = ConfigReader.getProperty("authorization.url");

        Response authResponse = authenticationControllerService.authorizeAdmin(RestAssured.baseURI);
        String responseBody = authResponse.getBody().asString();

        authorizationToken = authResponse.jsonPath().getString("token");
        System.out.println("Authorization token: " + authorizationToken);

        SharedContext sharedContext = SharedContext.getInstance();
        sharedContext.setAPIAuthToken(authorizationToken);
        sharedContext.setResponseBody(responseBody);
    }
    public String getAuthToken(){
        return authorizationToken;
    }

    @After("@UI")
    public void cleanUp(Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            scenario.attach(CommonMethods.takeScreenshot(), "image/png", scenario.getName());
        }
        CommonMethods.takeScreenshot(scenario);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        DriverUtils.getDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

Note that my 'public void setUp()' method in Hooks shows the tag @UI in the @Before as '@Before("@UI")' above it. I somehow had removed the '@UI' tag from above the 'Scenario' line in my Feature File. So, I wasn't calling the 'setUp' method in the very first place. Adding that fixed everything, so the beginning of my Feature File looks like this:

```
Feature: ARCCP-T001 - Sanity Test of PROD COMPANY Client Portal Essential Functionality

@ProdSmoke @TC1.38 @ARCCP-T138 @TestCaseKey=ARCCP-T138 @UI
Scenario: User logs in, clicks essential buttons, logs out, logs in, logs out
```